Two square minimax
Your want to choose two non intersecting square sub grids such that they have no common rows or columns. The objective is to maximise the sum of beauties of both square sub grids.
The beauty of a sub grid is defined as the difference value within that sub grid.
Find the maximum possible sum of beauties for the selected two sub grids

This looks like a question for a piece of coursework. Show what you have worked out so far.
